# How can rpubs with leaflet maps be made to output full screen?

Tags: r, leaflet, knitr

I am trying to save leaflet maps to [rpubs](https://rpubs.com/).

A [recent leaflet outputs](https://rpubs.com/shenqiny/648164) has an inset map with title.
Another is a [full screen leaflet output](https://rpubs.com/kwpeters/648109).

For the life of me cannot figure out how to change Rmd and chunk settings to display only leaflet map as full screen like in the [2nd example above](https://rpubs.com/kwpeters/648109).

Sample code below

```
---
output: html_document
---

{r pressure, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
r_birthplace_map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # use the default base map which is OpenStreetMap tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852,
             popup="The birthplace of R")
r_birthplace_map
```

Knits to this:
[image: Inset leaflet map in rpub]

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example was published directly from the map in RStudio Viewer. That is, you run the code in the R console, generate the map (which is an HTML widget) in the Viewer, click the `Publish` button, and publish it to RPubs:

[image: publish HTML widgets to RPubs]

It is not straightforward to generate a full screen HTML widget in R Markdown. You will have to use some CSS (to get rid of margins). I don't have time to provide the full CSS code (the answer in the first paragraph might be what you actually want). To begin with, you need to use the chunk option `out.width = '100%'` to make sure the map takes the full width of the container.

Comment: Direct from viewer is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!